# How to add fade-in animation to a component when it is loaded in react

Tags: reactjs, animation, react-router, single-page-application, fadein

I have an app with a nav bar and I have added react-router to app.js with routes to all the different components. I have use NavLink on all navigation buttons, so no reloads. Now, I want to add fade-in animation to a component when I mount it(press the navigation button for it)

I have no idea if it's even possible like this. I know of ways to make it work but then I have to change the entire navigation and also structure of the app.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's definitely doable and shouldn't require changing the structure of your application at all! You'll just need to make use of [CSS Animations](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp).

For a quick example, using this CSS and adding `className={'example-style'}` would give your component a fade-in animation lasting 3 seconds:

```css
.example-style {
  animation: fade-in 3s;
}

@keyframes fade-in {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 100;
  }
}
```

To see it in action, check out [this code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-fog-20exm4).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks! I'm actually new to react so was confused a lot and never thought it would be that simple. it worked. I also found out about a cool library named framer motion

Comment: CSS Opacity has a value from 0 - 1